# How to copy the slots of a boost signal

Tags: c++, boost, boost-signals

Is there a way to get the slots a signal connected to? i.e, i want to copy the slots of a signal from one instance of a class to another

I have a signal in my class and run into the following error. This is probably because this class is used in STL containers.

```
1>c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\signals\detail\signal_base.hpp(150): error C2248: 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
1>          c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\noncopyable.hpp(27) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable::noncopyable'
1>          c:\boost_1_52_0\boost\noncopyable.hpp(22) : see declaration of 'boost::noncopyable_::noncopyable'
1>          This diagnostic occurred in the compiler generated function 'boost::signals::detail::signal_base::signal_base(const boost::signals::detail::signal_base &)'
1>  test.cpp
```

so, i decided to put a copy constructor and connect the signal to the slots of the parameter signal and then i get the following error,

```
1>d:\workarea\boostsignalsEx\test.h(26): error C2663: 'boost::signal1<R,T1>::connect' : 2 overloads have no legal conversion for 'this' pointer
1>          with
1>          [
1>              R=void,
1>              T1=int
1>          ]
```

If i remove the const qualifier for the copy constructor parameter, I get another error..

```
1>d:\workarea\boostsignalsEx\test.h(40): error C2558: class 'test' : no copy constructor available or copy constructor is declared 'explicit'
```

This is the sample code I'm working on

```
class test{
public:
boost::signal1<void, int> sig;
test(const test& t) { t.sig.connect(sig);}; 
void attach(boost::function1<void, int> f) {sig.connect(f);}
};
```

guess chaining the signals will not work because i am not sure if the copy constructor parameter object will out live "this" object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Boost signals are non-copyable by design and thus cannot be used in STL containers. pointers to signals can be used instead as mentioned in this [Blog](https://anteru.net/2005/12/06/59/).

The signals are made movable which can be used in c++11 containers.

Answer (score 4):

You just connect the signal to the new target:

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ee3e3839d6955df9)**

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>

typedef void(Sigature)(int);
typedef boost::signals2::signal<Sigature> Signal;
typedef Signal::slot_type                 SlotType;

class test{
    public:
        Signal sig;

        test() = default;
        test(const test& other) { *this = other; };

        test& operator=(test const& other) { sig.connect(other.sig); return *this; }

        void attach(SlotType const& f)   { sig.connect(f); }
        void trigger(int i) const        { sig(i); }
};

int main()
{
    test a, b;
    a.attach([](int i) { std::cout << "subscribed to a:      " << i << "\n"; });
    a.attach([](int i) { std::cout << "also subscribed to a: " << i << "\n"; });

    std::cout << "Trigger via a:\n";
    a.trigger(42);

    b = a;

    std::cout << "\nNow via b:\n";
    b.trigger(43);
}
```

Prints

```
Trigger via a:
subscribed to a:      42
also subscribed to a: 42

Now via b:
subscribed to a:      43
also subscribed to a: 43
```

Comment: That was a neat example.. But connecting one signal to another do not work if the first object is deleted before the send object is triggered.
    `test *a = new test(), *b = new test();
     a->attach([](int i) { std::cout << "subscribed to a: " << i << "\n"; });
    a->attach([](int i) { std::cout << "also subscribed to a: " << i << "\n"; });
    std::cout << "Trigger via a:\n";
    a->trigger(42);
    (*b) = (*a);
    delete a;
    std::cout << "\nNow via b:\n";
    b->trigger(43);`
and the output is,
`Trigger via a:
subscribed to a:  42
also subscribed to a: 42

Now via b:`